# GAS Client Handler Validation on List Boxes

Tags: google-apps-script

I am coding a simple UI web form in GAS.  I have several text boxes and list boxes.  I have added client handlers to validate the input on the text boxes on blur and they all work fine.  However, when I try to use the client handler on a list box it doesn't work.  For example, the first item in the list box is an empty string and I want to check that an item has been picked.  Whatever validation option I use, it fires.  I've tried validate length.  I thought perhaps the script might be picking up the index value of the list so I tried option and range. Also, a no-go.  I would guess the script is working with a null value which is short-circuiting any validation.  Any tips?  When the widget is a List Box this thing fires all the time regardless of the conditions.

```
var required_field = app.createClientHandler()
  .validateNotLength(widget, min, max)
  .forTargets(lblInfo)
  .setStyleAttribute('color','red')
  .setText('Please correct errors in red NOW.')
  .forTargets(lbl)
  .setStyleAttribute('color','red')
  .forTargets(widget)
  .setStyleAttribute('background', '#ffe7e7');
widget.addBlurHandler(required_field);
```

Comment: See the open bug [Issue 1226](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1226).
There is a bug with ClientHandlers and ListBoxes such that regardless of the validation the handler will always fire.

Comment: Issue 1226 is now said to be [fixed](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1226#c12).

Answer (score 1):

I was interested in this issue so I ran a couple of tests and ended up with a workaround that might be interesting. The code is a bit long but I didn't find any way to make it shorter and still clear ;-)

This version is working, there are a few comments to suggest how to make it 'transparent' and also how to demonstrate that the handlers validation doesn't work on listBoxes.

Tell me what you think ;-)

EDIT : I've put a [version online](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwpo1YtexOD873ioYU0xXnClL-asiBM8UBazfAoRRRaM5gDqga2/exec) for a quick test.

```
 function showtest() {
   var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('ListBox Clienthandler test');
   var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
   var lb = app.createListBox(false).setId('myId').setName('myLbName').setWidth(350);
   var former = app.createTextBox().setName('former value').setId('former').setWidth(350);
   var textbox = app.createTextBox().setName('text').setId('valtext').setWidth(350)//.setVisible(false);// set it visible to test how it works, invisible to use it 'transparently'
   var label = app.createHTML("<BR><BR>Use this textBox as a button, click on it to update its value,<BR>the Client handler doesn't fire when selected color = white<BR>(if you set the upper textBox invisible then it works as if the<BR>listBox had the handler)<BR><BR>")    
   // add items to ListBox
   lb.setVisibleItemCount(7);
   lb.addItem('white');
   lb.addItem('pink');
   lb.addItem('orange');
   lb.addItem('green');
   lb.addItem('yellow');
   lb.addItem('red');
   lb.addItem('cyan');
//  
   panel.add(textbox);
   panel.add(lb);
   panel.add(label);
   panel.add(former);
   var handler = app.createServerClickHandler('click').addCallbackElement(panel);
   lb.addClickHandler(handler);
   app.add(panel);
   doc.show(app);
 }
//
function click(e) {
   var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
   var value = e.parameter.myLbName
       if(value==''){value='white'}
   var textboxvalue = e.parameter.text
       if(textboxvalue==''){textboxvalue='none'}
   var text=app.getElementById('valtext')
       text.setText(value)
   var lb=app.getElementById('myId')
   var former=app.getElementById('former')
//   var handlerval = app.createClientHandler().validateNotMatches(lb, 'white') // this line puts handler on listBox and doesn't work
   var handlerval = app.createClientHandler().validateNotMatches(text, 'white')  // this line puts handler on TextBox and works as expected
     .forEventSource().setText("Click here for Former Value = "+textboxvalue+" / present value = "+value)
     .forTargets(lb).setStyleAttribute("background", value)
      former.addClickHandler(handlerval);   
   return app;
 }
```

**EDIT 2 :**

here is another possibility to simulate (**almost** exactly) the function you need : ([online version](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbye87E1QhRlr1Ri57uGg3LMuWIUX3GeogNhuIOXyiWSvHKA-dY2/exec))

```
     function showtest() {
       var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
       var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('ListBox Clienthandler test');
       var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
       var lb = app.createListBox(false).setId('lb').setName('lb').setWidth(350);
       var label = app.createHTML("<BR>You forgot to choose a value in the list").setVisible(false).setId('label');
       lb.setVisibleItemCount(7);
       lb.addItem('');
       lb.addItem('pink');
       lb.addItem('orange');
       lb.addItem('green');
       lb.addItem('yellow');
       lb.addItem('red');
       lb.addItem('cyan');
       var othertextbox = app.createTextBox().setText('other question');
       var grid = app.createGrid(4,1)
           grid.setWidget(0, 0, lb)
           grid.setWidget(1, 0, label)
           grid.setWidget(3, 0, othertextbox)
       panel.add(grid)
       var handler = app.createServerBlurHandler('alert').addCallbackElement(panel);
       lb.addBlurHandler(handler);
       app.add(panel);
       doc.show(app);
     }
    //
function alert(e) {
   var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
   var lb = app.getElementById('lb')
   var label = app.getElementById('label')
   var value = e.parameter.lb
       if(value==''){
  lb.setStyleAttribute("background", 'red');
         label.setVisible(true)
           }else{
  lb.setStyleAttribute("background", 'white');
         label.setVisible(false)
           }
   return app;
```

Comment: I was trying to get the clienthandler to fire before the submit button was clicked.                                                'var required_field = app.createClientHandler()
      .validateNotLength(widget, min, max)
      .forTargets(lblInfo)
      .setStyleAttribute('color','red')
      .setText('Please correct errors in red NOW.')
      .forTargets(lbl)
      .setStyleAttribute('color','red')
      .forTargets(widget)
      .setStyleAttribute('background', '#ffe7e7');
    widget.addBlurHandler(required_field);'

Comment: I know ... but since it doesn't work I was trying to find a workaround ;-)

Comment: Until a Googler or a "super User" shows how to make it work I would think it's a bug (or at least that it doesn't work as it would normally work without returning any error, which is almost the same ;-)

Comment: I just added a workaround with example that behaves almost exactly as you want (I hope), the only difficulty is that the user have to focus on the list at least once... I guess one could find a solution to that ...

Answer (score 1):

Client handlers dont work with ListBox. But don't forget that you always have an option with Server handlers which are applicable in most of the cases when you can 1-2 seconds lag in reaction